# Point to quad expansion with Geometry Shader

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am new to the geometry shader, so I am trying to make a geometry shader that will take a point and create a quad with texture coordinates, just as an example to see how the geometry shader works. Here is the code I have written:

```
Texture2D txDiffuse : register( t0 );
SamplerState samAnisotropic
{
    Filter = ANISOTROPIC;
    MaxAnisotropy = 4;
};

cbuffer cbFixed
{
    //
    // Compute texture coordinates to stretch texture over quad.
    //

    float2 gTexC[4] = 
    {
        float2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        float2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        float2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        float2(1.0f, 0.0f)
    };
};

cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register( b0 )
{
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;
}
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 Pos : POSITION;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float3 Pos : POSITION;
};

struct GeoOut
{
    float4 PosH    : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex     : TEXCOORD;
    uint   PrimID  : SV_PrimitiveID;
};

VertexOut VS( VS_INPUT input )
{
    VertexOut output;

    output.Pos = input.Pos;

    return output;
}

[maxvertexcount(4)]
void GS(point VertexOut gin[1], uint primID : SV_PrimitiveID, inout TriangleStream<GeoOut> tristream)
{
    float4 v[4];
    v[0] = float4(gin[0].Pos + float3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), 1.0f);
    v[1] = float4(gin[0].Pos + float3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 1.0f);
    v[2] = float4(gin[0].Pos + float3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), 1.0f);
    v[3] = float4(gin[0].Pos + float3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 1.0f);

    GeoOut gout;
    [unroll]
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        gout.PosH = mul(v[i], World);
        gout.PosH = mul(v[i], View);
        gout.PosH = mul(v[i], Projection);
        gout.Tex = gTexC[i];
        gout.PrimID = primID;

        tristream.Append(gout);
    }
}

float4 PS( GeoOut input) : SV_Target
{
    //return txDiffuse.Sample( samAnisotropic, input.Tex );
    return float4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
}
```

When I compile this code, I get a blank screen. At first I thought it may be a texture problem, so I tried having the pixel shader output white, but it did not help. Next I thought it may not show because of the way the triangle is wound, so I disabled back face culling, but it still did not help. I'm not sure what to try next. Any ideas on the problem?

Comment: Remember that Geometry Shader requires [Feature Level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx) 10.0+ hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not ever worked with geometry shaders, but I think the way you're calculating `gout.PosH` is wrong. It should be

```
float4 p = mul(v[i], World);
       p = mul(p, View);
       p = mul(p, Projection);
gout.PosH = p;
```

See where you went wrong? Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow that fixed it thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that error. I copied over my vertex shader code and edited it a little bit, so I just assumed it was correct.